# Thread 1 exc_bad_instruction (code=exc_i386_invop subcode=0x0) error while clicking sth nil

Tags: ios, swift

I am getting this error while I'm clicking onto my button without entering anything or entered only 1 character. 
How to overcome this issue?

Here is my code:

```
let word = txtWord.text // Code
let checkWordLast = word!.characters.last // e
let checkWordChar1 = word![word!.startIndex.advancedBy(1)] // d

if checkWordLast  == "e"{

        lblWord.text = word! + "b" // Adding one character if last char is e
   // output : Codeb

    }else if (checkWordLast == "e") && (checkWordChar1 == "d"){
        lblWord.text = word! + "Swift"// Adding "Swift" if the last characters are "de"
   // Output : CodeSwift
    }
```

As I said, it works normal when i put more than 1 characters in my text area but not working when i leave it empty or only one char

Comment: It worked ! Thanks a lot! Sorry, I just started to learn how to code in Swift, so forgive me for my silly issues :)

Comment: Upvote if that was useful for you

Comment: i would but you wrote it as comment, therefore there is no button to up vote also i noticed another bug after a few trying new strings, ie. I don't get any problem while clicking onto button right now but getting problem when i entered one character only, i tried my best but not fixed yet. do you know any answer for it? if you know please let me know as an answer and i would love to give up vote for you(even if you don't know any answer give this answer as an answer please, while it shows as a comment i can't vote this answer up

Comment: I have wrote my previous answer as an answer.As far as your second problem is concerned the issue is again with only one character or no character ? have not you put the condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must be getting the fatal error: Can't form a Character from an empty String in your console. you need to put your

```
let checkWordChar1 = word![word!.startIndex.advancedBy(1)]
```

code in a condition i.e. if word count is greater than 1 then this operation should be done.